# Light Gremlin Server - GraphDB / Access via Node.Js Gremlin Lib

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, orientdb, gremlin-server, arcadedb

I'm looking for a light gremlin server with a graphDB to bundle with my project to be installed on a Windows PC. The gremlin server should be able to be accessed by the Node.JS Gremlin Client.

I found the following providers, and each has another issue that doesn't let me try them out on Windows.

- **OrientDB**: https://orientdb.org/getting-started

  Issue: Connection via Node.JS is working fine. Also fetching of vertexes. It's failing when adding a new vertex: `'Illegal char <:> at index 0: :contains_2_955793167.pcl'`
- **ArcadeDB**: https://arcadedb.com/

  Issue: https://github.com/ArcadeData/arcadedb/issues/1265
- **Bitsy**: https://github.com/lambdazen/bitsy

  Issue: https://github.com/lambdazen/bitsy/issues/42

The provider should be able to store the graph in the file system.

- Can anyone help me with the issues?
- Does anyone know a better provider for this approach?

Comment: Try to run the script from the ArcadeDB home directory with: `bin\server.bat`

Comment: Still the same issue, see GitHub Issue

Comment: The latest version of TinkerGraph now includes support for transactions via TinkerTransactionGraph. If you want something lightweight using that with a Gremlin Server might suffice. You can set TinkerGraph up to save to disk on exit, but you could also from code force that to happen more often. Another option might be [JanusGraph backed by BerkeleyDB](https://docs.janusgraph.org/storage-backend/bdb/#:~:text=JanusGraph%20backed%20by%20BerkeleyDB%20supports,of%20time%20for%20larger%20graphs.)